# Insert data after mysql started in a docker container

Tags: python, mysql, docker, dockerfile

I am using docker to start mysql service in a container. After the container starts, I want to insert some data to database automatically via python scripts. This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

EXPOSE 3306

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD 123456

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3 \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 init.py
```

The last row runs the script to add some data to database but this time mysql service has not started yet so it fails when running `docker build`. How do I accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), the MySQL entrypoint will automatically execute any files with `.sh`, `.gz` or `.sql` scripts found in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. So, create a script  to execute your Python script for you. If you call this file `01-my-script.sh`, your Dockerfile will look like this:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

EXPOSE 3306
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD 123456
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip 

# Copy requirements in first, and run them (so cache won't be invalidated)
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --user -r requirements.txt

# Copy SQL Fixture
COPY ./01-my-script.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-my-script.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-my-script.sh

# Copy the rest of your project
COPY . .
```

And your script will only contain:

```
#!/bin/sh

python3 /app/init.py
```

Now, when you bring up your container, your script will execute. Monitor the execution of the running container with `docker logs -f <container_name>` to make sure your script is running.